# How to map Elasticsearch Java API results to JSON?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

How can I convert an Aggregation in the Java API to a JSON result?

I've had some success using the toXContent methods to serialize an aggregation to JSON. However, these appear to be internal APIs. Are the toXContent methods a safe way to serialize to JSON?

Comment: Could you share some code example to clarify your question?